# Rails 3 to Rails 4 upgrade results in abnormally slow page load times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm upgrading an application from Rails 3 (latest) to Rails 4.0.  This has resulted in page load times that are tremendously slow.  In one case a page that previously rendered in less than one second now takes more than 4 HOURS to load.

We have been trying to profile the application and have gotten nowhere so far.

```
Before

Rails 3.2.19
Ruby 1.9.3-p547

After

Rails 4.0.13
Ruby 1.9.3-p547
```

[Also, I know this is not a great question as I'm not providing enough details.  I will edit and add details as I get more info and/or if there are specifics you can provide me that would help me to provide additional feedback.  I am not trying to be vague with my post.  I just don't have shit to go on right now.]

Comment: How on earth would a page take 4 hours to load? Do web servers even allow requests that long?

Comment: You could start by profiling your app or using New Relic in development mode to find the bottleneck.

Comment: @spickermann I put in new relic and Ruby prof and ironically new relic is throwing a bunch of exceptions so we haven't been able to get anything useful out of it. We're working through that and taking other approaches to profiling in the meantime as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a performance issue in the rails-observers gem.  It may be related to this issue as described on Github.

https://github.com/rails/rails-observers/issues/35

We ended up monkey patching ActiveModel::Observer as at the time of posting this a fix has still not been released.

```
# config/initializers/rails_observer_monkey_patch.rb
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  ActiveModel::Observer.class_eval do
    def self.observe(*models)
      models.flatten!
      models.collect! { |model| model.respond_to?(:to_sym) ? model.to_s.camelize.constantize : model }
      redefine_method(:observed_classes) { models }
    end
  end
end
```